# codeigniter create custom a array caching system

Tags: codeigniter, caching

I want to develop a system where as any user logins i want certain information about our erp system to be stored in 4-5 different multidimensional arrays, and this arrays can be used by any ajax call or any controller or model function to get data from them.

Suggest me some way so i can move that way and create my own array based caching system for my erp..this is basically to save my SQL calls for small data, which i can fetch and save initially as user logins and remove as he logouts.

Comment: 1) Your caching scheme is up to your implementation and what works best for it. How much data, how often does it change, what is the collision rate given common caching schemes, how much memory are you willing to sacrifice?; 2) Have you considered just using CI based sessions for this kind of data? It's already designed for this purpose, and I'm sure there is some sort of library already out there to assist in this (typing this SUPER fast as I'm busy at work so I haven't checked)

Comment: dude this data which i want to cache may change once in a month..but what i want is which is best working way...SESSION can they fulfill my wish?? or some GLOBAL arrays which i can access from any controller or method of CI??